# Как вывести одномерный массив в виде матрицы?

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Почему данный массив не выводится в виде матрицы ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] gamePanel = new int[400];
    final int POINT = 7;

    for (int i = 0; i < gamePanel.length; i++) {
        gamePanel[i] = 0;
        System.out.print(gamePanel[i] + " ");
        if (gamePanel.length % 20 == 0) System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Для примера, такой выводит в виде таблицы
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // 400
                table.add(0);
                System.out.print(table.get(i) + " ");
                if (table.size() % 10 == 0) System.out.println(); // %20
            }

Comment: Потому что `gamePanel.length % 20 == 0` всегда истинно, ибо остаток от деления 400 на 20 таки равен 0. Замените `gamePanel.length` на `i`

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] gamePanel = new int[400];
    final int POINT = 7;

    for (int i = 0, n = 0; i < gamePanel.length; i++, n++) {
        gamePanel[i] = 0;
        if (n == 20) {
            System.out.println();
            n = 0;
        }
        System.out.print(gamePanel[i] + " ");

    }
```

попробуй так.

Answer (score 1):

Размер массива одинаковый, поэтому у вас не работало. Нужно было у индекса `i` остаток от деления проверять:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] gamePanel = new int[400];

    for (int i = 0; i < gamePanel.length; i++) {
        if (i % 20 == 0)
            System.out.println();

        System.out.print(gamePanel[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Можно немного поиграться, используя java8 stream:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] gamePanel = new int[400];
    final int chunk = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < gamePanel.length; i += chunk) {
        int[] subArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(gamePanel, i, i + chunk);
        String result = Arrays.stream(subArr)
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

---

**PS.**

`if (i != 0 && i % 20 == 0)` - более точное условие, которое не даст вывести на новую строку сразу же, т.к. `i % 20 == 0` -> `True`